# I want implement ASMediasFocusDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, github

I want to use https://github.com/autresphere/ASMediaFocusManager to my project,
but I never learn OC language.
On introduce page mentioned that

> Implement its delegate ASMediaFocusDelegate. The delegate returns mainly a media URL, a media title and a parent view controller.

ASMediaFocusDelegate should implement :

```
(UIViewController *)parentViewControllerForMediaFocusManager:(ASMediaFocusManager *)mediaFocusManager;

(NSURL *)mediaFocusManager:(ASMediaFocusManager *)mediaFocusManager mediaURLForView:(UIView *)view;

(NSString *)mediaFocusManager:(ASMediaFocusManager *)mediaFocusManager titleForView:(UIView *)view;
```

How do i use these code in Swift?
thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.in **xxx-bridging-Header.h** add `#import "(this your OC file.h)"`
>
> 2.command + b
>
> 3.in your swift

```
class xxx: UIViewController, ASMediaFocusDelegate{
    var name:OCClassName = OCClassName()
    override init(){
       super.init()
       self.name.delegate = self
    }
    func parentViewControllerForMediaFocusManager(mediaFocusManager: ASMediaFocusManager) -> UIViewController{
        
    }
    ......
}
```

I think swift use OC is same

Comment: Can you please add all three protocol methods.